# Ensuring date can be added in past

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

What can I do to this piece of code to ensure that it can allow absences to be added in the past as well as the future? Whenever I attempt to add anything in the past, it is appears to want to still give me the error that I cannot add an absence in the past. I'm not even sure how to code to ensure it can, or which bit to delete. I'm aware there is a bit of code that is not allowing me to, but I'm not sure which bit and what to delete. I am not extremely skilled at JavaScript but it is in my project and I am unsure what to do with it.

```
dateValid: function () {
    var s = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).required()) {
        var date = new Date(s);

        if (!isNaN(date)) {
            if (date >= Date.parse(new Date().toDateString())) {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                validation.showError("Past", $(this).attr("name"));
                $(this).addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            validation.showError("Invalid", $(this).attr("name"));
            $(this).addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else return false;
},

dateRangeValid: function (toDate) {
    var s = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).required()) {
        if (toDate.required()) {
            var dateFrom = new Date(s);
            var dateTo = new Date(toDate.val());

            if (!isNaN(dateFrom) && !isNaN(dateTo)) {
                if (dateTo >= dateFrom) {
                    if (dateFrom >= Date.parse(new Date().toDateString())) {
                        $(this).removeClass("error");
                        toDate.removeClass("error");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        validation.showError("Past", "date");
                        $(this).addClass("error");
                        toDate.addClass("error");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    validation.showError("Invalid", "date");
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                    toDate.addClass("error");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                validation.showError("Invalid", "date");
                $(this).addClass("error");
                toDate.addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            validation.showError("Required", "dateTo");
            $(this).addClass("error");
            toDate.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        validation.showError("Required", "dateFrom");
        $(this).addClass("error");
        toDate.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
},
```

Comment: Does your program prevent adding a selected date in the past, or does the jQuery datepicker not allow you to select one in the first place?

Comment: My program prevents me from adding a date in the past, it allows me to pick it. Sorry, is this the wrong piece of code to be looking at? Otherwise I can select another bit.

Comment: Yeah, this code doesn't do much.  Do post the error message, if any, and the code for `addAbsence`.

Comment: The error is coming from the UI itself. It is saying a programmed in error message that will not allow me to add it in dates. However, if I get rid of this red alert bar message, it will just show me a blank red alert bar, knowing there should be an error, but I haven't added it in.

Comment: I'm stupid, updated the CORRECT piece of code... sorry ^^;

Comment: It is the dateRangeValid that is causing the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
            if (dateTo >= dateFrom) {

                // This if statement checks if dateFrom is today or later!!
                if (dateFrom >= Date.parse(new Date().toDateString())) { 

                    $(this).removeClass("error");
                    toDate.removeClass("error");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    validation.showError("Past", "date");
                    $(this).addClass("error");
                    toDate.addClass("error");
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Replace with

```
            if (dateTo >= dateFrom) {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
                    toDate.removeClass("error");
                    return true;
            }
```

and there should no longer be a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been a great help! :-)